# unfamiliar SQL syntax

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have come across an SQL statement designed for a DB2 database (iSeries) which is of the format below. What i don'y understand is the FROM clause. DATABASE.TABLE makes sense. But the part beginning from the Colon `:` is not familiar. Please can someone tell if this seems to be valid? The only place where I have seen Colon used in SQL is for host variables

```
SELECT DISTINCT FLD1,
                    FLD2,
                    FLD3,
                    FLD4
    FROM 
                    DATABASE.TABLE:TABLE1 TABLE1
    WHERE 
                    FLD5 = 'MFG'
                    AND FLD6= '1'
```

Comment: I think the colon `:` is the catalog separator in DB2 iSeries ("catalog" being the SQL standard's name, I think iSeries calls that differently)

Comment: I can find no reference to that syntax in the manual, and I have never seen it in DB2 for i. I don't think it is valid.

Comment: I agree with @jmarkmurphy...I've never seen such syntax on DB2 for i.

Comment: usually the syntax is "select * from yourlibrary.yourfile"

Comment: You `came across` it where? In program source code? In a SQL procedure? In a web page? Somewhere else? If we had more context, there might be possible explanations. Edit the question to add background.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like compiled program SQL the :field is substituted at run time.

```
C+ UPDATE CORPDATA/EMPLOYEE
C+    SET SALARY = SALARY * :PERCNT
C+    WHERE COMM >= :COMMI
C/END-EXEC
```